# Installing ant design with npm

Tags: node.js, webpack, widget, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install ant design in my project.
npm install antd --save

Results in the following warnings:

```
npm WARN react-lazy-load@3.0.12 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-lazy-load@3.0.12 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-slick@0.14.11 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-slick@0.14.11 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN draft-js@0.10.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-rc but none was installed.
npm WARN draft-js@0.10.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-rc but none was installed.
npm WARN rc-hammerjs@0.6.6 requires a peer of react@^0.14.3 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Inside the dependencies i can see:

> ```
> "@types/react": "15.0.24",
> "@types/react-dom": "15.5.0",
> ```

Does this mean that ant design is incompatible with these versions of react? What am i doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` are TypeScript definitions (https://www.npmjs.com/~types). You're getting npm WARN, which is not an ERROR. Have you tried use the antd package to see if you get any errors?

Comment: Sorry, i might have misread something there, altough i get these messages when i try to run the command. I'm new to this so i might be wrong on the topic. As soon as i dug deeper i will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an older version of react which doesn't support ant-design yet. Try installing the latest version of react.